# How can I perform clustering on a list of words and ratings as columns?

Tags: python, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I want to perform clustering to give words meaning like good, neutral and bad. My dataset is in the format :

```
product id       describers       ratings
     1         [great,lovely,        4
                 wonderful]
     2         [bad,wonderful,       3
                  amazing]
     3         [poor, bad]           1
```

I want to cluster these words in the list based on ratings like obviously logically wonderful,lovely,amazing should be clustered as one and bad, worst etc. as another cluster. How can I cluster this type of dataset and then assign these cluster values of positive, neutral, negative ?

Comment: I doubt that clustering is the right tool here.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after seems to be [sentiment analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis) at the word level. Since at the word level context is limited (in your case you have groups of words, but generally one doesn't even have that), a common approach is to use pre-made corpora. Naturally, such approach has many limitations, such as being limited only to a prespecified language and ambiguity of words, but still is a good point to start.

Consider using any of [SentiWordNet](https://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/), [Bing Liu's Opinion Lexicon](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html#lexicon) or any of [these other resources](http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net/lexicons.html#resources). I've found these resources, via this [question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-downloadable-database-of-positive-and-negative-words).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import re
import nltk 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
global str


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path\\dataset.csv')

print(df.shape)

# Here we are doing some sentiment analysis, and distilling the 'review_text' field into positive, neutral, or negative, 
# based on the tone of the text in each record.  Also, we are filtering out the records that have <.2 negative score; 
# keeping only those that have >.2 negative score. This is interesting, but this can contain some non-intitive results.  
# For instance, one record in 'review_text' literally says 'no issues'.  This is probably positive, but the algo sees the
# word 'no' and interprets the comment as negative.  I would argue that it's positive.  We'll circle back and resolve 
# this potential issue a little later.
import nltk
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
nltk.download('punkt')

from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
df['sentiment'] = df['review_text'].apply(lambda x: sid.polarity_scores(x))
def convert(x):
    if x < 0:
        return "negative"
    elif x > .2:
        return "positive"
    else:
        return "neutral"
df['result'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x:convert(x['compound']))
```

My 'review_text' is a field with comments, 'sentiment' is a score, and based on that score, you will end up with a negative, neutral, or positive rating.